# Is it legal to use self-defense against police brutality?

Tags: criminal-law, police, self-defense

Is it self defense if a police officer were assaulting; let’s say my uncle, and punch or push away the officer to stop him from hurting my uncle would that be legal?

Comment: The concept of self-defense does not involve the "defense" of a third party; and assaulting a police officer is generally illegal everywhere.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch: It's true that protecting a third person is not self-defense, by definition; but it could still be legal under some other concept.  And using force on a police officer who is doing something illegal may not be assault.  But to answer this question we need to know the jurisdiction, i.e. where is this taking place.

Comment: All legal questions aside, if you actually do this, it is very likely in practice that the officer will use force on you, possibly deadly force, and that you will be arrested if you are still alive.  You may eventually win in court, or you may not, but it won't be very much fun.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch That doesn't seem to be correct. According to https://lawshelf.com/courseware/entry/defense-of-others many jurisdictions do allow "self-defense" to protect a 3rd party if that party was in a situation where self-defense was permitted.

Comment: Also [answered here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27975/10) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/16695/10).